# Create and assign AWS elastic Beanstalk Spring instance to VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I want to create 3 AWS Elastic Beanstalk instances and assign them to VPC with internal IP addresses. As you can see I have a default VPC created and running:

[image]

When I try to create a new AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance under the same Ohio region into the menu I see just see empty list of VPC:

[image]

[image]

Do you know what configuration I need to do in order to assign AWS Elastic Beanstalk instances to VPC?

EDIT:

I use this form to create VPC:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide exact setps you took to create your instance in a VPC, or at least what are you attempting to do.

Comment: Sure. I added picture how I create VPC.

Comment: This is vpc. Whatever about subnets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you did not select the `Application Platform` in Elastic Beanstalk's application creation process.

Try picking a platform before configuring more options.

[image: screenshot]